# VirtualBox 5.1 - Can not mount SATA device - a real partition (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, partitioning

The host is Windows 10. I am trying to mount partition as SATA device on one VM but when the VMDK file is attached it throws the following error:

[image]

ws1-pt.vmdk is generated as explained [here](http://virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idm7097).

I have tried with "Enable Host I/O Cache" enabled and disabled.

With simple words, what I need is VM using real partition as virtual disk.

EDIT: I tried to do the same thing on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop as a host. The result was the same. See the command I had executed and the disks and partitions my system has:

[image]

The tool generated two virtual disks: "ws1_disk.vmdk" and "ws1_disk-pt.vmdk". I just guess that I have to use the one with suffix "-pt", but here is what happens when it is mounted:

[image]

The other virtual disk is mounting successfully and it is actually working as needed. The host can access the partition on the guest while it is running. The guest can not access the host's other partitions. **So the question is what is the difference between both virtual disks and why actually the second is giving that error?**

Thanks (:

Edit 2: Sorry I have attached the wrong image of the error. The actual error is not for the permissions (as visible on the image) but:

*Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/kostadin/VirtualBox VMs/ws1/ws1_disk-pt.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).*

Edit 3:
Content of ws1_disk3.vmdk

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=47e5b41a
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="partitionedDevice"

# Extent description
RW 63 FLAT "ws1_disk3-pt.vmdk" 0
RW 1922 ZERO 
RW 63 FLAT "ws1_disk3-pt.vmdk" 63
RW 188901376 ZERO 
RW 63 FLAT "ws1_disk3-pt.vmdk" 126
RW 1985 ZERO 
RW 9238528 ZERO 
RW 1710 ZERO 
RW 63 FLAT "ws1_disk3-pt.vmdk" 189
RW 275 ZERO 
RW 286050304 FLAT "/dev/sdc7" 0
RW 63 FLAT "ws1_disk3-pt.vmdk" 252
RW 1985 ZERO 
RW 4192256 FLAT "/dev/sdc8" 0
RW 6512 ZERO 

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.geometry.cylinders="16383"
ddb.geometry.heads="16"
ddb.geometry.sectors="63"
ddb.uuid.image="1af2b0f7-4f8a-4a58-9eea-a50d132cbd65"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="78138ce1-4220-4ed1-9e27-789f58123c3e"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders="1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads="255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors="63"
```

The content of ws1_disk3-pt.vmdk is some binary/serialized data.
Result of executing the following command

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk /dev/sdc
```

is

```
Number  Type   StartCHS       EndCHS      Size (MiB)  Start (Sect)
5       0x07  0   /32 /33  1023/254/63         92237         2048
6       0x82  1023/254/63  1023/254/63          4511    188905472
7       0x83  1023/254/63  1023/254/63        139673    198146048
8       0x82  1023/254/63  1023/254/63          2047    484198400
```

Comment: Since the instructions you link to are for Linux and you're on Windows, it's a bit difficult to figure out where you went wrong but I'm certain you could not have done it properly with those instructions.

Comment: The command is the same, I used VBoxManage.exe! I used diskpart command to list drives and partitions. The creation of the VMDK passed without any problems.

Comment: Apparently you don't want help as I merely asked you the command you've put in and you argued instead of giving it.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the exact command, it is because I do not remembered it exactly as it was executed. Let me do that again and I will post the exact command which generates the VMDKs (strangely they are two) in the original post.

Comment: Does this work for you in the latest version of VirtualBox 5.0? VB 5.1 is fairly new and may have introduced a (regression) bug with this feature.

Comment: Where was the VMDK file created? If on Linux, it won't work because of the differences in the way the OS references devices. If on Windows, is it the same machine as the host?

Comment: @kronenpj I had one try with 5.0.24 before trying with 5.1 and it was the same thing. You may be confused because of my messy post but I have tried once on windows 10 and once on Ubuntu 16.04 I have never messed the files, they are completely different machines and in both cases the second VMDK file which has the suffix "-pt" in the name is not working. I am prejudiced for this to be a bug in VirtualBox. The other VMDK however is working fine.

Comment: Please add the contents of the VMDK files to the question along with the output of `VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk /dev/sda`, changing `/dev/sda` as appropriate for your system. My previous experience with creating raw disk/partition VMDK files is that only one is created and it works as expected.